# Implementación de metodos

Tags: java, array, sensor

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual, tengo una clase vehículo (Ya implementada) y estoy en desarrollo de una clase sensor, en cuanto a esta aquí esta la clase UML es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que llevo es el siguiente

```
    public static int tamano=8;
    public static int posAnadir=0;
    private String tipo;
    private double valor;
    public static Sensor[] sensores = new Sensor[8];

    public Sensor(){

    }

    public Sensor(String t, double v){
        this.tipo=t;
        this.valor=v;
    }

    public String getTipo(){
        return this.tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String t){
        this.tipo=t;
    }

    public double getValor(){
        return this.valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double v){
        this.valor=v;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "El tipo de sensor es " + tipo + " y su valor es " + valor + ".";
    }

}
```

En el método toStringSensores (4to en la clase UML) tengo que iterar una lista de sensores de la clase Sensor (Y que retorne una lista concatenada de los sensores almacenados) y en el método  cantidadSensores (5to en la clase UML) tengo que implementar los sensores creados hasta el momento (He pensado en implementar un contador en posAnadir). He intentado ya varias formas de implementar estos métodos pero no he podido lograrlo ¿Cual seria la mejor forma?

Comment: El 4to metodo te refieres a getValor y el 5to setValor o te refieres a cuales 4 y 5?, lo otro es que necesitas que retorne el arreglo de sensores que ahí o que necesitas?, por que es mejor no convertir eso a una cadena de texto, por que una cadena de texto es la unica cosa que se me ocurre para pensar en lo que dices de 'que retorne una lista concatenada de los sensores almacenados', pero si no añades ningun sensor al usar ese metodo y solo iteras, entonces por que en vez de iterar no simplemente retornas los sensores?

Comment: Con respecto al 5to metodo dices que quieres implementar los sensores creados hasta el momento, implementar... te refieres con implementar a añadir los sensores que llevas al momento? o enrealidad es al revez, es decir el 4 metodo hace la funcion del 5 y el 5 del 4?, no se no queda muy claro.

Comment: He realizado varios cambios en el post para que sea más entendible, había redactado mal y daba a entender los métodos del código que llevaba y más no los de la clase UML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para el metodo `toStringSensores` solo es convertir a cadena de texto así que seria así:

```
public String toStringSensores(){
   return Arrays.toString(this.sensores);
}
```

Para obtener la cantidad de sensores solo debes usar la propiedad length de los arreglos:

```
public int cantidadSensores(){
    return this.sensores.length;
}
```